# I don't get any documents back from my elasticsearch query. Can someone point out my mistake?

Tags: filter, elasticsearch

I thought I had figured out Elasticsearch but I suspect I have failed to grok something, and hence this problem:

I am indexing products, which have a huge number of fields, but the ones in question are:

```
{
  "show_in_catalogue": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "index": "no"
  },
  "prices": {
    "type": "object",
    "dynamic": false,
    "properties": {
      "site_id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": "no"
      },
      "currency": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "gross_tax": {
        "type": "integer",
        "index": "no"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to return all documents where "show_in_catalogue" is true, and there is a price with site_id 1:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "prices.site_id": "1",
      "show_in_catalogue": true
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

This returns zero results. I also tried an "and" filter with two separate terms - no luck.

A subset of one of the documents returned if I have no filters looks like:

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "site_id": 1,
      "currency": "GBP",
      "value": 595,
      "gross_tax": 1
    },
    {
      "site_id": 2,
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": 745,
      "gross_tax": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope I am OK to omit so much of the document here; I don't believe it to be contingent but I cannot be certain, of course.

Have I missed a vital piece of knowledge, or have I done something terminally thick? Either way, I would be grateful for an expert's knowledge at this point. Thanks!

*Edit*:

At the suggestion of J.T. I also tried reindexing the documents so that `prices.site_id` was indexed - no change. Also tried the bool/must filter below to no avail.

To clarify, the reason I'm using an empty query is that the web interface may supply a query string, but the same code is used to simply filter all products. Hence I left in the query, but empty, since that's what Elastica seems to produce with no query string.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "show_in_catalogue": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "prices.site_id": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have site_id set as {"index": "no"}. This tells ElasticSearch to exclude the field from the index which makes it impossible to query or filter on that field. The data will still be stored. Likewise, you can set a field to only be in the index and searchable, but not stored.

I'm new to ElasticSearch as well and can't always grok the questions! I'm actually confused by you query. If you are going to "just filter" then you don't need a query. What I don't understand is your use of two fields inside the term filter. I've never done this. I guess it acts as an OR? Also, if nothing matches, it seems to return everything. If you wanted a query with the results of that query filtered, then you would want to use a

```
-d '{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {},
         "filter": {}
      }
   }
}'
```

If you just want to apply filters is the filter that should work without any "query" necessary

```
-d '{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "show_in_catalogue": true
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "prices.site_id": 1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried your suggestions and clarified my question. I was playing around with an empty query simply so I could populate it once the filters worked on the full set of results. Still can't get anything out of it, but I'll keep hacking.

Comment: Aha - it worked if I indexed everything I wanted to filter on. I didn't realise you had to index things to filter - I thought it only applied to query searches! If I accept this answer, would you clarify your edit to explain this, so future readers find it? Thanks!

Comment: Edited! Sorry, I was on my mobile phone when I reexamined your question. So, the edit did not stand out regarding the index no.